# SSH.NET RunCommand To Save Command Output to File

Tags: c#, ssh, stdout, ssh.net, runcommand

I'm trying to run a command on a remote server via SSH.

I need the output of the command that is run to be saved in a file on that remote server.

I've been attempting to this the following way

```
// ssh is the SshClient which is already set up
ssh.Connect();
ssh.RunCommand("echo 1 > C:\test.csv"); //Doesn't create a file
ssh.Disconnect();
```

Why doesn't this work with SSH.NET? If I run this via putty using the same credentials it works perfectly fine.

EDIT (Working Code):

I did some more playing around and have found the following to work:

```
// ssh is the SshClient which is already set up
ssh.Connect();
var shell = ssh.CreateShellStream("cmd.exe", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
var reader = new StreamReader(shell);
var writer = new StreamWriter(shell);
writer.AutoFlush = true;

while (!shell.DataAvailable)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //This wait period seems required

writer.WriteLine("echo 1 > C:\test.csv");

while (!shell.DataAvailable)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //This wait period seems required

ssh.Disconnect();
```

While that works I still don't understand what's really happening here. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 4):

Try this function:
Just save the result to a variable or write the result using StreamWriter

```
private void writeMe()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename)
    {
        string result = eSshCom(command);
        sw.WriteLine(result);
    } 
} 



private string eSshCom(string getCommand)
            {
            this.res = "";

            var connectionInfo = new KeyboardInteractiveConnectionInfo(ipaddress, 22, username);

            connectionInfo.AuthenticationPrompt += delegate(object asender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs xe)
            {
                foreach (var prompt in xe.Prompts)
                    {
                    if (prompt.Request.Equals("Password: ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                        prompt.Response = password;
                        }
                    }
            };

            using (var ssh = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
                {
                    ssh.Connect();
                    var cmd = ssh.RunCommand(getCommand);
                    this.res = cmd.Result;
                    ssh.Disconnect();

                }
            return this.res;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I took bits of it and made it work for my code. I still don't really understand why it doesn't work though.

Comment: If it helps kindly give the answers an upvote for appreciation. Thanks